# Download all mp3 files on a site and rename them in the process

Tags: linux, download, debian, mp3, wget

I want to download all episodes of a podcast that is poorly organized. Every episode is placed in a separate subfolder on the server, and they all have the file name "file.mp3" - I'd like to download them, sequentially downloading, then renaming, and then moving on to the next file. Using something like wget causes each file to overwrite the previous file, given they have the same file name.

Answer (score 1):

`wget` normally doesn't overwrite files, it adds a number as a suffix:

```
file.mp3
file.mp3.1
file.mp3.2
...
```

But you can prevent that by calling it in a loop and using its `-O` option to specify the name:

```
count=0
urls=( http://example.com/folderA/file.mp3
       http://example.com/folderB/file.mp3
       http://example.com/folderC/file.mp3
)
for url in "${urls[@]}" ; do
    wget -O file-$count.mp3 "$url"
    (( count++ ))
done
```

Comment: I am on debian Wheezy CLI : How do I make your answer usable? I have tried to gather everything as one row `count=0 urls="folder/1.txt" for url in "${urls[@]}" ; do wget -O file-$count.mp3 "$url" (( count++ )) done` but it didn't work.

Comment: I forgot I also added a filelist. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Also, what shell are you running? The code shown here is the bash dialect.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this. The error is `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do' "`. My shell is "bash (Bourne Again Shell)" (cheap scaleway VPS)

Comment: @miodf: If you want to put everything to one row, you need to add semicolons to separate the statements. Why do you need just one line?